# Allowing any MAC admin user to run MySQL server on startup

Tags: macos, mysql, user, wordpress, mamp

I recently installed MAMP on our server in order to launch a Wordpress site. Though everything is working fine I am not the computer's main user, something which results in long downtime when it has to be rebooted for maintenance.

I was looking for a way to automatically load MAMP on start-up, regardless of who logs in. This lead me to run a script for loading the Apache and MySQL servers on start-up, using the files *startApache.sh* and *startMysql.sh* located in *Applications/MAMP/bin*. I found that the Apache server could be loaded from any admin user with no problem. The MySQL server however will only start when I log-in with my own account (the one under which the installation took place).

Being able to run these scripts without being prompted for a password would be a plus, but it is more important that any admin can start the MySQL server.

I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly a permissions problem on the files in MAMP/bin.

If you do `ls -l` in `/Applications/MAMP/bin` you will probably find that the MySQL start script or executable is set to '-rwx------' or similar so that only the owner can run them. Change the permissions via `chmod a+x filename` and it should fix it.

(I apologise for my less than precise answer but I removed MAMP a few months ago and now use VMs in Fusion for the same thing.)

As an alternative set the preferences for the MAMP application to `Start Servers when starting MAMP` and then run the application at user login.

Comment: Permissions for the _startMysql.sh_ file are `-rwxrwxr-x@ com.apple.TextEncoding`. It was a good guess, and I thank you, but I fear that was not the problem.

Comment: Could the problem rest in the MySQL database users' accounts?